# Pay Any Large Amount with 5- and 7-Coins

Tags: html

Develop a Python method change(amount) that for any integer amount in the range from 24 to 1000 returns a list consisting of numbers 5 and 7 only, such that their sum is equal to amount. For example, change(28) may return [7, 7, 7, 7], while change(49) may return [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7] or [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7] or [7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7].

To solve this quiz, implement the method change(amount) on your machine, test it on several inputs, and then paste your code in the field below and press the submit quiz button. Your submission should contain the change method only (in particular, make sure to remove all print statements).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not homework solving service.

Comment: subtract 7 until result is divisible by 5

Comment: It might not be homework, but I am interested what code has the author tried to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You're expected to [try to solve your problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098). If you get stuck somewhere then it's a good idea to ***ask a specific question*** here based on your own solution attempt; providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Just started programming, quite proud of this. Here you go:

To use: **print(change(amount))**

```
def change(amount):

  if amount < 24 or amount > 1000:
    return 'error'

  array = []

  while True:
    if (amount/5).is_integer():
      for i in range(int(amount/5)):
        array.append(5)
      return array

    array.append(7)
    amount += -7

    while amount > 0:
      break
```